# Cannot run docker based Windows container in Windows 10 VirtualBox VM on Mac OS X host

Tags: windows, macos, docker, virtualbox, hyper-v

I get the following error when I try to run a docker-based Windows container using the following commands:

```
docker pull microsoft/dotnet-framework
docker run -it microsoft/dotnet-framework cmd
```

> docker: Error response from daemon: container 31112532fbefca415cfb10134612cf4467c084e93e699b7caa320ca60f5df266 encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows system call: No hypervisor is present on this system. (0xc0351000)

Docker for Windows is set up in a Windows 10 Pro VM (using VirtualBox) on a Macbook Pro (Intel based, 2016, OS X El Capitan). In Docker's settings, I switched to using Windows containers. Is there a specific issue with OS X? Because I am able to make this work in a PC running Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: See if this thread helps you https://www.baswijdenes.com/portfolio/hyper-v-in-virtualbox-guide/. Also check in Windows 10 VM that hyper-v is installed and running fine. If not then you need to change acceleration settings to enable VM inside VM

Comment: @TarunLalwani I checked out that post. Most of the PowerShell commands in that article don't work on Windows 10. I have enabled Containers and Hyper-V features in the Windows 10 VM, via Windows Features management. VirtualBox settings for the VM shows the following under Acceleration: `VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging, PAE/NX, Hyper-V Paravirtualization`, so I am not sure what else I should be doing.

Comment: Are you able to launch Hyper-V inside the VM manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running Docker Windows containers on Windows 10, Hyper-V is required. This won't work with VirtualBox because [VirtualBox does not support nested virtualization](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032).

Instead you should Windows Server 2016 (WS2016) in the VirtualBox VM. WS2016 can run Docker Windows containers with process isolation, which doesn't require Hyper-V.

You can [trial WS2016 for free](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016/) and [Stefan Scherer maintains a set Vagrant scripts that automate setup and configuration](https://github.com/StefanScherer/docker-windows-box).

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, and for all the links!